# How to get the to, from, cc and bcc fields from mail composer in a callback for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, callback, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

Does anyone know if its possible and how to get the TO, FROM, CC, and BCC fields from a mail composer in a callback for the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Using MFMailComposer.

Cannot be done. The only delegate that you find for this is

[MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate)

> mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:

You can set it to some predefined values for once the user enters the MailComposer

By setting setToRecipients: and setCcRecipients:

But these settings are for BEFORE you give the user the control. After that you only get the above.

Comment: yes, i feared as much, will just wait a while to see if someone else can offer a workaround before i mark as accepted